# Importing pandas in windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pandas, import

I tried multiple methods with Anaconda and python both using version 3.6 and when I import pandas I'm getting the following error in my Windows machine

```
 import pandas
  File "D:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "D:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    import http.client as httplib
  File "D:\python3\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "D:\email.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas.io.sql as psql
  File "D:\python3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 14, in <module>
    import pandas.lib as lib
  File "pandas\lib.pyx", line 1, in init pandas.lib (pandas\lib.c:90879)
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 59, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:115313)
ImportError: cannot import name is_platform_windows
```

It seems to be environment related but I can't find anything related to this issue when I google this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was picking anything python script in my folder called email.py and that's causing the issue.